# GitLab git push and commit does not register change

Tags: git, gitlab

I am doing a school project due in about an hour, intro programming. We are supposed to write some code to answers some questions and then have a txt file that says we actually read the instructions. Well, I never actually saved the word "yes" into the "read.txt" file. I created a repo on GitLab on the web, I cloned the empty repo to my computer, moved the files into the newly created directory and executed

```
git config --global user.name "Surname Lastname"
git config --global user.email "school@mail.com"

git add assignment/code.js
git add assignment/read.txt

git commit -a -m "Done."

git push --set-upstream origin master
```

and now I am stuck because if I change the read.txt file content to "yes" and execute

```
git add assignment/read.txt
git commit -a -m "Done."
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

I get that it is already done.

```
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
Everything up-to-date
```

I have tried to remove the file from gitlab to re-add it but the changes are only local even though there are no errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to push your changes with:

`git push origin master`

Alternatively since you've already set `upstream`, it can be shortened to just `git push`.

Comment: `git push origin master => Everything up-to-date` When I check the file "read.txt" on the web inside the actual repo online, its blank. When I check the file in my local directory, it has the text. `git push => git push
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>`

 which if I follow the error just returns "Everything up to date."

Comment: That's strange. What's the output when you run `git branch`?

Comment: `* (HEAD detached from e422c21)
  master`